# Jquery Scripts not running properly when exected through Selenium(SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined ) in IE 9. But working properly in Web browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The below code is not working properly when given with Selenium.  It throws this error `SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined` in IE 9. But when it is run in Web browser console after removing the "\" sign it is working fine.

```
String scripts="var script=document.createElement('script');script.onload = function() {alert(\"Script loaded and ready\");};script.src = \"http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.js\";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);$(\"*\").hide();";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(scripts);
```

Comment: just use `'` instead of `"`, therefore you wont be needing `"\"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
String scripts="var script=document.createElement('script');
  script.onload = function() {alert('Script loaded and ready');};
  script.src = 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
   $('*').hide();";
```

just use `'` (single quotes) instead of `"` (double quotes), therefore you wont be needing `"\"`.

Comment: Thanks...once it is running, but on second time onwards it is throwing same error `"SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined "`.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by second time? Are you reloading the browser or re running the application or what is it?

Comment: When i execute the same script again in selenium, it is throwing the error. The first time when i run the script, it works. But from second time, it is throwing java error.